# VCS folder status in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I know it is possible to, if a file has been modified, mark the parent folder(s) also as modified (with a color) in Intellij. I have set up a new environment and after searching for about an hour (in the settings and on the web) I just am not able to find it. How/where can you configure this in Intellij-12?

Also wondering why this isn't the default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable it in `Settings` | `Version Control`:

[image: Show directories with changed descendants]

The options is called **Show directories with changed descendants**.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I did not see that. Time to call it a night I guess. Tx!